# PowerShell Add-Type Error: Invalid search path

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, msbuild

This code works perfectly fine when run by launching PowerShell from the start menu or from the PowerShell ISE but when I run it from inside Visual Studio during a custom build step I get the error.

```
$Signature = '
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
'

if ($Maximize) { $nCmdShow = 3 } else { $nCmdShow = 1 }
$pInvoke = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
```

Error:

> ```
> Add-Type : (0) : Warning as Error: Invalid search path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\atlmfc\lib\x64' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The
> system cannot find the path specified. '
> (1) : using System;
> At
> <Filepath>.ps1:22
> char:13
> + ...  $pInvoke = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $csClass -Name WindowAPI -Pass ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except
>    ion
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
> ```

Please help!

Comment: Add `-IgnoreWarnings` to `Add-Type` to supress, although you might want to check if something or someone set `%LIB%` machine or user-level env variable to include the path above and fix that.

Comment: is it VS2019 ??? because it looks like some paths like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2012\VC\atlmfc\lib have changed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\atlmfc\lib in VS 2019 and that may not be getting reflected when creating LIB env variable.

Comment: Yes it is VS2019